# Error: "githubAccountBlocked" "Your account has been temporarily blocked. Please try again later, or use a different account."

Tags: github, deno-deploy

I'm following along to the instructions on Deno as displayed [here](https://fresh.deno.dev/docs/getting-started/deploy-to-production) but I get the error

```
"githubAccountBlocked",
  "message": "Your account has been temporarily blocked. Please try again later, or use a different account."
```

When I click on the link for Deno Deploy Dashboard and then press continue to Github, it asks me first if I want to give Deno dashboard permission to which I say yes but then it tells me:

```
{
  "code": "githubAccountBlocked",
  "message": "Your account has been temporarily blocked. Please try again later, or use a different account."
}
```

Any idea what is causing this issue?

Comment: https://github.com/denoland/deno/discussions/15303

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jsejcksn pointed out in the link he provided:

"Deno say that we filter users because new accounts are often spammers. Try again in a week."